# How to create question/answer form?

Tags: forms, hooks, users

I need to create a textarea (textfield) that every user who visits the site be able to ask his/her question via this textarea (textfield), and then the content managers will answer the question and both answer/question will be published via a view.

I don't know how to implement such thing. creating a page which only shows the question textarea needs a module to create its form but how does this form can act as a field in a content type?!

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [answers](https://drupal.org/project/answers) module which creates the Question and Answers System for you.

But for the requirement you want, you could create a Content Type which is not published by default, and has Body Field as the Question asked by the User. For the answers to the question another textarea field can be added via Field UI. When the answers are given you can make the node published. Here you can add checkbox to let the user know his question has been answered.

You can then use [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to hide the new answer field from the user.

Comment: you mean I should redirect the visitors to the `/node/add/QA` page? seems it works, But is it possible to theme this page? and create capcha for submission button?

Comment: Definitely, use [captcha](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) module to add captcha to a form. You can google for theming.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a content type called QandA. This will have 2 fields - 1 called question and 1 called answer. Using the [field_permission](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module set it so only admins can fill in the answer. Then you could also use the [entity_relationship](https://drupal.org/project/er) module to create a relationship between the user and the QandA if this is required so users can see *their* question (maybe in their profile).

Then using the [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module create a rule to add a new QandA when a user registers. At this point you can also set the relationship between the user and the QandA.

Admins can then have a custom view to show unanswered questions to allow them to work though the list.

Creating a view of questions and answers will then be easy as it will just involve showing one content type, filtered to only show QandA's with answers.

Comment: There is no user. visitors will not register, they only ask their question and fill the capcha